# Fetch data via select according to logged user ID Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using the code below that returns the number of products registered per day:

```
$products = Product::select(DB::raw('count(id) as `number_products`'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') new_date"))
            ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
            ->groupBy('new_date')->orderBy('new_date') 
            ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
 $qtdProduct = ($products ->pluck('number_products')->toArray());
```

I need to do this now for the logged in user. I thought about using this:

```
where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
```

I inserted the line above and even then, continues to select all products ignoring the '**user_id**' logged. Where am I missing this? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a Policy for that:

```
php artisan make:Policy ProductPolicy --model=Product
```

and then you need to register the Policy inside AuthServiceProviders:

```
 protected $policies = [
    Product::class =>ProductPolicy::class,
];
```

Inside your policy you can manipulate your policies entries accord your methods inside your ProductController.

Good luck!

Comment: do I really need to do this? As I understand it, just my SQL clause: "where ('user_id', Auth :: user () -> id)
"is being ignored.

Comment: That's better to manage and manipulate the access to sql queries, plus you can add errors messages with sql errors